# Python: Regex a dictionary using user input wildcards

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, wildcard, file-handling

I would like to be able to search a dictionary in Python using user input wildcards.

I have found this:

```
import fnmatch
lst = ['this','is','just','a','test', 'thing']
filtered = fnmatch.filter(lst, 'th*')
```

This matches this and thing.  Now if I try to input a whole file and search through

```
with open('testfilefolder/wssnt10.txt') as f:
 file_contents = f.read().lower()
 filtered = fnmatch.filter(file_contents, 'th*')
```

this doesn't match anything.  The difference is that in the file that I am reading from I is a text file (Shakespeare play) so I have spaces and it is not a list.  I can match things such as a single letter, so if I just have 't' then I get a bunch of t's.  So this tells me that I am matching single letters - I however am wanting to match whole words - but even more, to preserve the wildcard structure.

Since what I would like to happen is that a user enters in text (including what will be a wildcard) that I can substitute it in to the place that 'th*' is.  The wild card would do what it should still.  That leads to the question, can I just stick in a variable holding the search text in for 'th*'?  After some investigation I am wondering if I am somehow supposed to translate the 'th*' for example and have found something such as:

```
regex = fnmatch.translate('th*')
print(regex)
```

which outputs  `th.*\Z(?ms)`

Is this the right way to go about doing this?  I don't know if it is needed.

What would be the best way in going about "passing in regex formulas" as well as perhaps an idea of what I have wrong in the code as it is not operating on the string of incoming text in the second set of code as it does (correctly) in the first.

Comment: Why don't you just use [`re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is just that you "have spaces and it is not a list," why not make it into a list?

```
with open('testfilefolder/wssnt10.txt') as f:
 file_contents = f.read().lower().split(' ') # split line on spaces to make a list
 filtered = fnmatch.filter(file_contents, 'th*')
```

Comment: Thanks for that Chris.  First I am trying to learn how to write these things in Python (I am pretty new), but am not even sure if I should in the end as I am going to be combining thousands of files.  Lists sound good to me, I am curious to know if this is the best option though.

Thanks again,